# Jest does work with react-navigation scrollview , SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, babeljs

When jest configured with "babel-jest": "^23.6.0" , it's not working. I'm getting Unexpected token import when i use ScrollView from react-navigation . Have gone through all the solutions for the opened issue related to unexpected token import.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "BitRiseSetup",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.7",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.50.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
};
```

**Output**

```
/Users/vivekkumar/Desktop/myProjects/BitRiseSetup/node_modules/@react-navigation/native/dist/Scrollables.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

       7 |     return (
       8 |       <SafeAreaView>
    >  9 |         <ScrollView />
         |          ^
      10 |       </SafeAreaView>
      11 |     );
      12 |   }

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
      at Object.get ScrollView [as ScrollView] (node_modules/@react-navigation/native/dist/index.js:29:12)
      at Object.get ScrollView [as ScrollView] (node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js:21:47)
      at Hello.render (Hello.js:9:10)
      at finishClassComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6625:31)
      at updateClassComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6588:10)

  console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8060
    The above error occurred in the <Hello> component:
        in Hello
```

Comment: have you checked any other topic on ["unexpected token import"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjestjs%5D+token+import)? there are literally dozens of them

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added ScrollView into the React-Native elements

```
import {
  Image,
  Alert,
  .
  .
  .
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
```

Then **you cannot directly close  tag** because its a view where the all content goes and you have to add content into the starting and ending tag of ScrollView

***Updated**

You can use it like this

```
<ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
  <SafeAreaView>
        {/* long content here */}
  </SafeAreaView>
</ScrollView>
```

This will not give you syntax error

Comment: Actually am using ScrollView from react-navigation not from `react-native`. you want me remove safeareaview and have scrollview first?

Comment: I didn't find any ScrollView element from react-navigation, but still I have updated answer you can use scrollview and safeareaview like that